# Spring Hateoas Resource List wihout content element tag

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-hateoas

Regarding Spring HATEOAS Resource Wrapper vs ResourceSupport extention, i have:

```
public class FolderDto<T> implements Serializable {
    private Number id;
    private String name;
    private final List<FolderDto<T>> folders;
    private final List<T> items;

    ...
}

public class BoardDto implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private Integer id;
    private boolean shared;
    ...
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    FolderDto<Resource<BoardDto>> folder = new FolderDto<Resource<BoardDto>>(0, null);
    FolderDto<Resource<BoardDto>> child = new FolderDto<>(1000, "root");
    folder.getFolders().add(child);
    child.getItems().add(new Resource<>(new BoardDto(333,"whiteBoard", true)));


    Resource<FolderDto<Resource<BoardDto>>> resource = new Resource<>(folder, linkTo(methodOn(BoardController.class).getBoards(null)).withSelfRel());

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();   
    mapper.writeValue(System.out, resource);
}
```

The result will be:

```
{
    "id":0,
    "nodes":[
        {
            "id":1000,
            "name":"root",
            "leaves":[
                {
                    "content":{
                        "id":333,
                        "name":"whiteBoard",
                        "shared":true
                    },
                    "links":[{"rel":"board","href":"http://localhost/internal/boards/333"}]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "links":[{"rel":"self","href":"http://localhost/internal/boards"}]
}
```

How can i have this without the content element wrapper using Resource ?

In order to split responsibilities the rest controller logic (hateoas) entities should be as clean as possible and not have dependencies to other libs.

Desire result (obtained with extends ResourceSupport) :

```
 {
    "id":0,
    "nodes":[
        {
            "id":1000,
            "name":"root",
            "leaves":[
                {
                    "id":333,
                    "name":"whiteBoard",
                    "shared":true,
                    "links":[{"rel":"board","href":"http://localhost/internal/boards/333"}]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "links":[{"rel":"self","href":"http://localhost/internal/boards"}]
}
```